# ¿Cómo guardo la información de un JSpinner a mi Base de datos en MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, spinner

bueno mi problema es qué no sé qué código utilizar para guardar un JSpinner a mi base de datos en MySQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imágen se puede ver este JSpinner el cual al introducir su edad quiero que se guarde en una tabla que estoy haciendo.

```
            String SQL="insert into Empleado (nombre, edad, puesto, domicilio, estadc, sucur, grado, dinero)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            
           PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
           
           pst.setString(1, txtName.getText());
           pst.setString(2, (String) txt_edad.getValue());
           
           int seleccionado = jPuesto.getSelectedIndex();
           pst.setString(3, jPuesto.getItemAt(seleccionado));
           
           pst.setString(4, txtDom.getText());
           
           int seleccionado1 = jEstC.getSelectedIndex();
           pst.setString(5, jEstC.getItemAt(seleccionado1));
           
           int seleccionado2 = jSucur.getSelectedIndex();
           pst.setString(6, jSucur.getItemAt(seleccionado2));
           
           int seleccionado3 = jGrado.getSelectedIndex();
           pst.setString(7, jGrado.getItemAt(seleccionado3));
           
           pst.setString(8, txtDinero.getText());
           
           pst.execute();
```

Entonces el problema radica en este código que me invente viendo a más páginas pero no sé si alguien sepa cuál es el código correcto, gracias por todo.

```
pst.setString(2, (String) txt_edad.getValue());
```

Por si acaso dejo foto de mi BD creada en workbench.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas la definición de la tabla te indica que `edad` es de tipo `INT`, entonces en el `PreparedStatement` debes de indicar el tipo de dato correcto, el código seria:

```
stm.setInt(2, (int) txt_edad.getValue());
```

Esto asumiendo que `txt_edad` es de tipo `javax.swing.JSpinner`.